# Union from all feature classes from feature set using ListFeatureClasses

Tags: arcpy, union

I want to use the union tool in ModelBuilder to combine ALL the features from two feature data sets from two different gdb together.

I use ArcGIS 10.5.1 with an advanced license. I tried to use the arcpy.union_analysis().

How can I automate the input, so all the features from a feature class are selected?

I tried so far:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:Test\01_Data\15_Test.gdb"
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset='A_Test')
for fc in featureclasses:
arcpy.Union_analysis([fc,"C:\Test\14_Test.gdb\Other_Union"],"C:Test\01_Data\16_Output.gdb","NO_FID")
```

It is not working the way I hoped it would. It does not take all the features from the list rather every feature at one time and then overwrites the output.

I think the For iteration is not the right thing to use - is there a possibility to take all the listed features as input?

I use ArcGIS 10.5.1 with an advanced license.

@BERA helped me find the right solution:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:Test\01_Data\15_Test.gdb"
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset='A_Test')
arcpy.Union_analysis(featureclasses,r"C:Test\01_Data\16_Output.gdb","NO_FID")
```

Comment: Two questions is one too many. Please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the "One question per Question" policy.  The default behavior is to overlay all features, so that question is confusing.

Comment: @BERA I will try ListFeatureClasses and then post the script (if it should not work). Thank you :)

Comment: What license level are you using?  For Union this makes a difference.

Comment: @PolyGeo Version 10.5.1

Comment: That's a version number. License level will be one of Basic, Standard or Advanced.

Comment: Sorry - I have an advanced license.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: @Vince: I already did. Can you help now?

Comment: How many feature classes are there? If it is too many to add them to the Union tool manually your resulting feature class will be chaos. What are you going to do with the results?

Comment: At maximum 7 Input Data for one union so don't worry about the lenght of my Attributtable. 
But I want to group my results to four different topics - so 4 unions in on model. All unions with every feature in the defined feature set. 

With the final results I want to compare different alternatives for the same four topics - that is way the model gets iterated 8 times....so i don't want to select 32 Inputs with at least 2 Features manaually.

Comment: It is the width/number of columns i think about, not the number of rows. Are you sure it is Union tool you want and not merge?

Comment: I get your concerns about the rows (worst case I get 32 rows), but yes I want to use a union.

Comment: Like I said: NOT the rows, but the columns... Your question is still unclear, screenshots would help. There should be no problem building a model manually, you dont need to list all features. Just drag and drop them to the model and connect to Union. In your code attempt you should not use a for loop. Input to union should be the list `featureclasses`, use r in front of the path and you need to specify the output name, not only the gdb, like this: `arcpy.Union_analysis(featureclasses, r"C:\Test\01_Data\16_Output.gdb\name_of_output_fc")`

Comment: I meet columns not rows sorry...32 columns and 10 rows...not pretty I know. But I can delete/disslolve them later on. 

If I take featureclasses as input it workes perfectly - thank you

Comment: @BERA looks like a question you can provide an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you want. But to fix your code you should not use a for loop since Union wants a list of input feature classes not the feature classes one by one. You have already created the list called `featureclasses`.

The output should have a [r in front of the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034822/unknown-python-expression-filename-r-path-to-file) and you also need to specify the name, not only the output geodatabase.

```
arcpy.Union_analysis(featureclasses, r"C:\Test\01_Data\16_Output.gdb\name_of_output_fc")
```